# Grails 3 "Command not found run-script"

Tags: grails3.2.0

I am trying to use "run-script" to run Groovy scripts that are wrapped in a Grails context, as referenced in the documentation

http://docs.grails.org/3.2.x/guide/introduction.html

I am using grails 3.2.4

```
$ grails run-script
| Error Command not found run-script MyExample
```

Why is the command not found?

Answer (score 0):

Just update **grailsVersion** in the *gradle.properties* file.